# 'void (*)(const char*)' to 'void (*)()' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm using [this](https://github.com/scogswell/ArduinoSerialCommand) Arduino library to tokenize and parse commands received over a serial port but I have some strange pointer issue. I seen some other solution on stackoverflow(as suggested) but none of them helped me fix my issue.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong with this `addCommand` function. Everything seems fine to me

Call pingHandler, pass "PING" character string to function definition & that's all.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include "SerialCommand.h"

SerialCommand sCmd;

void pingHandler (const char *command) {
  Serial.println("PONG");
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);

  sCmd.addCommand("PING", pingHandler);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if(Serial.available() > 0){
    sCmd.readSerial();
  }
}
```

I'm getting this **error**

```
C:\Users\GK_Desk_07\Documents\Arduino\ArduinoSerialCommand\ArduinoUnity\ArduinoUnity.ino: In function 'void setup()':

C:\Users\GK_Desk_07\Documents\Arduino\ArduinoSerialCommand\ArduinoUnity\ArduinoUnity.ino:13:38: warning: invalid conversion from 'void (*)(const char*)' to 'void (*)()' [-fpermissive]

   sCmd.addCommand("PING", pingHandler);

                                      ^

In file included from C:\Users\GK_Desk_07\Documents\Arduino\ArduinoSerialCommand\ArduinoUnity\ArduinoUnity.ino:2:0:

sketch\SerialCommand.h:84:8: note: initializing argument 2 of 'void SerialCommand::addCommand(const char*, void (*)())'

   void addCommand(const char *, void(*)());   // Add commands to processing dictionary

        ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument of `addCommand` should be a pointer to a function taking ***no arguments***, as shown in [the example](https://github.com/kroimon/Arduino-SerialCommand/blob/master/examples/SerialCommandExample/SerialCommandExample.pde).

Try changing `pingHandler` to:

```
void pingHandler () {
  const char *command = sCmd.next();
  Serial.println("PONG");
}
```

Comment: Note that use of empty parentheses in `void pingHandler() {}` [is an obsolescent feature](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.11.6)

Comment: It would have been, if this was C. But [it is C++](https://github.com/kroimon/Arduino-SerialCommand/blob/master/SerialCommand.h).

Comment: Hmmm. It was the C tag that brought me here; still, I didn't think that Arduino was actually C++.

Answer (score 4):

The [definition for `addCommand`](https://github.com/scogswell/ArduinoSerialCommand/blob/master/SerialCommand.h) is

```
void addCommand(const char *, void(*)()); // Add commands to processing dictionary
```

So it expects a `void(*)()` (function without any arguments in C++, with any arbitrary arguments in C) but you're giving it a `const char*` argument

Change your `pingHandler` to

```
void pingHandler (void) {
```

## Edit:

Since Arduino is C++ you don't need the `void` part inside parentheses

```
void pingHandler () {
```

Comment: This is tagged [tag:c++], where we normally express "takes no arguments" with `()`, unlike [tag:c], where we must write `(void)`.  The latter is not idiomatic in C++.

Comment: @TobySpeight it was tagged C at first